# Как в String добавить перенос строки

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне записать такую строку в `String`

> Ля-ля-ля ля-ля-ля
>   Ля-ля-ля ля-ля-ля

```
String s1="Ля-ля-ля ля-ля-ля"+"Ля-ля-ля ля-ля-ля";
```

NeatBeans предлагает только конкатенацию строк. А как все-таки записать с учетом переноса строки.

Comment: Между Ля-ля-ля ля-ля-ля и Ля-ля-ля ля-ля-ля был перенос строки

Answer (score 15):

```
String s1 = "Ля-ля-ля ля-ля-ля"+ "\n" + "Ля-ля-ля ля-ля-ля";
```

Comment: String s1 = "Ля-ля-ля ля-ля-ля\nЛя-ля-ля ля-ля-ля";

Comment: Какой хитрый. А может, человеку нужно именно соединить две какие строки с переносом между ними.

Comment: тогда лучше StringBuilder использовать, чисто из производительности

Comment: Тоже можно

Comment: @Gorets - java компилятор не достаточно умен что-бы сделать это вместо вас?..

Comment: @mikillskegg, "NeatBeans предлагает только конкатенацию строк" судя по всему аффтору нужна какая-то неведомая магия :)

Ну да мне не жалко, тем не менее вопрос выше актуален, ибо если компилятор это не делает за вас, то это печаль

Comment: Ну, ладно... Это была просто шутка...

Comment: Да можно, конечно, и StringBuilder использовать.

Comment: @mikillskegg вопрос не об этом, если я не буду использовать, но при этом буду иметь много конкатенации строк, оптимизирует ли это java компилятор и, если да, то какой смысл использовать StringBuilder, если нет - почему?

Comment: В явном виде StringBuilder надо использовать внутри циклов.

Comment: @AlexWindHope вполне, кроме цикла

Answer (score 8):

Используй `System.lineSeparator()`. Это сделает перевод строки и в Windows и в Linux.

```
String s1="Ля-ля-ля ля-ля-ля"+System.lineSeparator()+"Ля-ля-ля ля-ля-ля";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String s1 = "Ля-ля-ля ля-ля-ля\nЛя-ля-ля ля-ля-ля";
```

(или то же, но с конкатенацией) будет самым частым ответом, причём для многих C-подобных языков.
[Перевод строки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) на разных платформах и их версиях может быть разным, но в Java используются Unicode-cтроки, так что [работает \n](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Однако в случае форматированных строк, чтобы вставить платформо-зависимый разделитель строк, [нужно](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html) использовать символ *"%n"*:

```
String s1 = String.format("%s%n%s", "Ля-ля-ля ля-ля-ля", "Ля-ля-ля ля-ля-ля");
```

-- (в данном случае на место *"%s"* подставятся второй и третий аргумент метода *format()*)

Answer (score 2):

```
String song = "La-la-la \n LaaaaaLaaaaa \n";
```